# jQuery UI Tabs: Mismatching fragment identifier (jQuery 1.71, UI 1.8.16)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm using jQuery 1.71 and jQuery UI 1.8.16 and am getting the infamous jQuery UI Tabs: Mismatching fragment identifier error.

Can anyone help? I thought there might be issues with versions of UI and jQuery - but I am pretty sure my versions are fairly modern.

Thanks in advance.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    tab_holder = jQuery('#dl-tabs');
    tab_holder.tabs({
    event: 'mouseover'
});

tab_holder.tabs('option', 'disabled', false);
    tab_holder.tabs('rotate', 5000);
    tab_holder.mouseleave(function () {
     tab_holder.tabs('rotate', 5000);
    });
});
```

the HTML code is as follows:

```
<div class="tabs ui-tabs ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" id="dl-tabs">
<ul class="ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">
        <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active"><span>Content</span></li>
                    <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active"><span>Content</span></li>
                    <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active"><span>Content</span></li>
                    <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active"><span>Content</span></li>
                    <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active"><span>Content</span></li>
 </ul></div>
```

Comment: Is this your markup before or after tabas are applied? Use the examples on [the tabs documentation page](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs) to see what your markup should look like.

Comment: After. I should have noted that this markup works fine on an old stack of jquery 1.4 and an older jquery ui. I'm trying to upgrade and I ran into these issues.

Comment: Interesting... Could you show your markup before applying `tabs`?

Comment: <div id="dl-tabs" class="tabs">
 <ul><li><span>Content</span></li><li><span>Content</span></li><li><span>Content</span></li><li><span>Content</span></li><li><span>Content</span></li></ul></div>

Comment: Hmm--I don't see the error here: http://jsfiddle.net/sbkjn/ (the tabs aren't working correctly though) but you should be using `li`s containing `a` tags with `href`s referencing content elements in `div`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK - I didn't include all of my markup (e.g. the linked to divs [as you pointed out Andrew], when using your jsfiddle I figured out that using the code I used, the referenced div in the jquery has to encompass the list and the content. it was solved by adding a new div wrapping around both and calling tabs on that.

Thanks Andrew you really helped big time!